# WooCommerce product update – check if a field's value has changed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the following code to hook a product update in woocommerce:

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'on_update_product', 10, 2);
function on_update_product($product_id, $product){
    // code here
}
```

Is there a way to check if certain fields have changed, compared to the previously stored version of the product?

Thanks!

Comment: Wich field do you want to check? And can you explain more about why you want to to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, forgot about this! I'd like to check basically every field of the product so that I only need to do work if a field has changed (for optimization purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this that I know is with hashes.

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'on_update_product', 10, 2);
function on_update_product($product_id, $product){
    //create a hash from data you want to track
    $hash = md5(json_encode([
        $product->get_name(),
        $product->get_price(),
        "etc....."
    ]));
    //get the hash before the product update
    $hashBefore = get_post_meta( $product_id, "hashKey", true );
    //check if de hash is diffrend
    if ($hash !== $hashBefore) {
        // Store the new hash
        add_post_meta($product_id, "hashKey", $hash);
        // exicute your code
        // .....
    }

    // you can duplicate this process if you want to track individual fields
    $hash2 = md5(json_encode([
        $product->get_sku(),
    ]));
    $hashBefore2 = get_post_meta( $product_id, "hashKey2", true );
    if ($hash2 !== $hashBefore2) {
        add_post_meta($product_id, "hashKey2", $hash2);
    }
}
```

To get data out of the product object check this resource:
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

I hope this suits your situation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend hooking to another action. I use it to identify changes in orders, but it actually can use for any woocomercce related object types (orders, products, coupons, subscriptions etc.)

```
woocommerce_before_[objectName]_object_save
```

for your purpose you can use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_product_object_save', 'identify_product_change', 100, 2);
function identify_product_change($product, $data){

    $posted_info = $_POST; // Use this to get the new information 
    $price = $product->get_price(); //Example of getting the "old" product information

}
```

Having that said, you need to be careful, since this hook may be initiated from different triggers (some background processes etc). You may want to have some caution measurements:

- use `$_POST['action'] == 'editpost'` to make sure the action is an
  actual "Update" click from the admin edit page.
- use `(is_admin())` to limit it only to admin area
- you can use `(!defined('DOING_CRON'))` to make sure it won't run on any cron execution
- and you can use `(!defined('DOING_AJAX'))` to make sure it won't run on ajax calls

this way you can limit it only to the exact action you wish to catch.

Comment: This will not work, except for `$product->get_price()`. The new values are already present in the product object . `get_price()` returns the old value because price changes will be made with '_regular_price' or '_sale_price'. `$product->get_changes()` show you which values are changed. At this point, the product object is not saved to database. So you can access the previously stored version like this: `$old_product = wc_get_product( $product->get_id() ) `